# How to Combine Cells with Same Value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below table that exists for 5,000 plus rows.

| Object ID | Object Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | D |
| 2 | E |
| 3 | R |

I am trying to combine in comma separated list all the values in a third cell all Object values where the Object ID is the same. The result of the formula should be.

| Object ID | Object Value | Dervied Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A,B,C |
| 1 | B | A,B,C |
| 1 | C | A,B,C |
| 2 | D | D,E |
| 2 | E | D,E |
| 3 | R | R |

What is the best way to achieve this? Please note I am using Excel on MAC.

Comment: Simple: use this tô fill down: `=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=A2))`

Comment: This might help you 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5018-excel-group-and-concatenate.html

Comment: Or =BYROW(A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(B:B,A:A=x)))) to spill with one formula

Comment: `=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(B2:B7,A2:A7=s))))`. Pretty sure there are a few duplicates around here on SO though.

Comment: I would rather use something like this instead of repeating the same duplicates for derived column: `=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(s,IF(ROW(x)=XMATCH(s,A:A),TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(B:B,A:A=x)),"")))`

Comment: I modified the formula based on the cell range:

=MAP(D11:D20235,LAMBDA(s,IF(ROW(x)=XMATCH(s,D11:D20235),TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(F11:F20235,D11:D20235=x)),"")))

but I am getting a #Name? error. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @Ankit there is a typo as well, try now `=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,IF(ROW(x)=XMATCH(x,A:A),TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(B:B,A:A=x)),"")))`

Comment: Thanks, Mayukh. I keep getting a #SPILL error for the same range of 20K cells, even when I only have one cell filled out with the formula:

=MAP(D11:D20235,LAMBDA(x,IF(ROW(x)=XMATCH(x,D11:D20235),TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(F11:F20235,D11:D20235=x)),"")))

Comment: Also, I tired searching SO for the solution to my problem. the ones I am getting on google or SO essentially create a unique object ID 1 and a cell with all object value concatenated. I am trying to create an outcome for every entry of object ID for this. So if Object ID 1 has 5 rows, each of the 5 rows should have the concatenated values of the 5 object values.

Comment: Try this one then: `=MAP(D11:D20235,LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(F11:F20235,D11:D20235=s))))` you may need to clear all the cell values in the range to keep it empty

Comment: I prefer using let function for single cell formulas, just a preference.

`LET(id, A2:A7, val, B2:B7, MAP(id, LAMBDA(m, TEXTJOIN(", ", , FILTER(val, id = m)))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use anyone of the two functions, as per the comments posted:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=s))))
```

---

Or using <kbd>REPT( )</kbd> instead of <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> as mentioned by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(B2:B7,A2:A7=s))))
```

---